# Using Ember component's methods inside template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've just started learning Ember and one thing I'm confused that if I can access component's method inside the template.

For example, I have a `note-list` component that render list of `note-line` as follow:

```
<ul class="list">
  {{#each notes as |note|}}
    {{note-line note=note index=@index selected=(isSelected note)}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The `note-list` component is defined as:

```
Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: '',
    isSelected(note) {
        return note.id === this.get('selectedNote').id
    }
})
```

But I'm getting error `Assertion Failed: A helper named 'isSelected' could not be found`.

I think I could solve it with helpers, but it seems to be not a good solution to create a separate helper for a behaviour of a specific component.

Please help to advise me some better way to deal with it.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you add the router part related to notes? There is a way of doing this via the `link-to` helper and a custom `activeClass`, that way you would let ember handle it instead of looping over the model and setting the property on each record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, your component can determine itself if it is selected or not. Indeed, you have a function `isSelected` that returns a boolean whether the note-line is selected or not.

You must consider using a computed property to achieve this.

The `note-line` component would be defined like :

```
Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: '',
    note: null,
    isSelected: Ember.computed('note', function() {
        return this.get('note.id') === this.get('selectedNote.id')
    })
})
```

Then, in your component template, `isSelected` is available as a simple component variable and is updated when `note` is updated.

Finally, you can simply use your component like this :

```
<ul class="list">
  {{#each notes as |note|}}
     {{note-line note=note index=@index}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

But in this case, as you pointed out in your comment, you would need to pass `selectedNote` to each component in order for them to update the `isSelected` property.

One way to do this would be to have a isSelected property in the model itself as documented [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/defining-models/). In your `model` function inside your `route`, you will just have to set this property like this :

```
model: function() {
    return this.store.find('notes')
     .then(function(notes) {
          notes.forEach(function(note) {
            note.set('isSelected') = true || false; // here will be implemented your function to determine if note is selected or not 
          });
          return notes;
        })
    })
}
```

Then in your component template, `isSelected` is available in `note` like any other attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in this case it seems like I need to pass the selectedNote into to `note-line`, i.e. `{{note-line note=note index=@index selectedNote=selectedNote}}`

I wonder if there's other ways to do it without passing the selectedNote, as the `note-line` actually only care about the note it show and if this note is selected.

Comment: I understand better what you want. Please see my updated answer.