# Ember 2 - Hide / show content component

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember.js-2

I have a component **app/components/offer-listing.js**:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  isOfferShowing: false,
  actions: {
    offerShow() {
      if (this.get('isOfferShowing')) {
        this.set('isOfferShowing', false);
      } else {
        this.set('isOfferShowing', true);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and his template **app/templates/components/offer-listing.hbs**:

```
<div class="offer__container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="gr-3">
      <div class="offer__avatar" style="background-image: url('{{ offer.avatar }}')"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gr-9">
      <div class="offer__name" {{action "offerShow"}}>{{ offer.firstname }} {{ offer.lastname }}</div>
      <div class="offer__age" {{action "offerShow"}}>{{ offer.age }} ans</div>
      {{#if isOfferShowing}}
        <div class="offer__description" {{action "offerShow"}}>{{offer.description}}</div>
      {{else}}
        <div class="offer__description" {{action "offerShow"}}>{{word-limit offer.description 50}}</div>
      {{/if}}

      {{#if isOfferShowing}}
        <div class="+spacer"></div>
        <a class="offer__button"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contacter par email</a>
        <a class="offer__button"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Voir le numéro de téléphone</a>
      {{/if}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

which is rendered in **app/templates/index.hbs**:

```
{{#each model as |offerUnit|}}
  {{offer-listing offer=offerUnit}}
{{/each}}
```

The example is working great, however I would like to hide every **"more"** content when a new one is showing.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "hide every "more" content when a new one is showing" ?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58469525/stackoverflow/ember-show-hide.png - As you can see, when we click on the text, the call actions buttons are showing. I would like to have just one open at the time.

Comment: Ok I understand better what you need. Please see my answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working solution for this is available here : [Using Ember component's methods inside template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219607/using-ember-components-methods-inside-template/32220588#32220588)

Basically, either you keep a reference to the selected element in your controller and pass it to each of your `offer-listing` components. This way they could compare themselves with this reference to known if they need to be displayed or not.

Or you set a flag in each of your `offer` model depending on whether is needs to be displayed or not.

Comment: In your opinion, what will be the best solution ?

Comment: I personally like the second one because it keeps my templates clean.

Comment: So at the end, I came up with a model value ```offer.isShowing```, I inject in my component the Store service, when we click on an offer, I loop each objects from the local store (peekAll), I set them to false and I set the current one clicked to true. Sounds right to you ?

Comment: Yes, but you could save some computation by just saving a reference to the currently selected `offer` so that you could just switch its `isShowing` property on and off instead of peeking all your data everytime.